# How to get and set Environment System Variable using Windows WISE Installation Package

Tags: windows, environment-variables, installation-package

Google searches have not produced something viable for me so I'm hoping someone here might have experience with this:

We're trying to do the following with WISE Installation Studio:

1. Does a certain environment system variable exist?

   a. If it does, get the value (It will be a file path in this case).

   b. If it doesn't, add the system variable.

   c. If adding the system variable determine what version of windows (32-bit/64-bit) is being used so we can use the `C:\Program Files\` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\` as the value.

It seems like it's something fairly straight forward to do, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it.

Any type of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out the issue after toying around with WISE and a Visual Basic script. Although, apparently there are other means of doing so using the MoveTables in the MSI itself. The details to the problem and my solution can be found on this [message board](http://www.appdeploy.com/messageboards/tm.asp?m=74792).

I hope other people can find it useful.